# How can I get the position of a recurring character in a string?

Tags: python, python-2.7, position

I have this string:

> |C100|0|1|F120570|55|00|32|754929|35150456228356008116550320007549291371271334|17042015|20042015|2077,14|1|2062,48|0,00|3729,51|9|0,00|0,00|3,51|0,00|0,00|0,00|0,00|0,00|0,00|0,00|0,00|0,00|

And I need to find the `index / position` of the 23rd "|" using Python.

Since I have more than one "|", I don't know how to do that..

I've found this code to find the second occurrence

```
def get_second_index(input_string, sub_string):
    return input_string.index(sub_string, input_string.index(sub_string) + 1)
```

but this one isn't helping me with my problem.

I thought that maybe I can get that with a loop like `while x < 23:` but I can't figure it out exactly how...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> [i for i, j in enumerate(input_string) if j == '|'][22]
>>> 154
```

Generates a list containing the index of each occurrence of `|` and then returns the 23rd element (=22 because lists are zero-indexed)

Answer (score 3):

The easiest I can think of is to loop through each character and keep the count of how many `'|'` you have found.

```
count = 0
for index, c in enumerate(string):
   if c == '|':
      count = count + 1
   if count == 23:
      print index
      break
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following regular expression to match exactly 23 '|' characters:

```
text = "|C100|0|1|F120570|55|00|32|754929|35150456228356008116550320007549291371271334|17042015|20042015|2077,14|1|2062,48|0,00|3729,51|9|0,00|0,00|3,51|0,00|0,00|0,00|0,00|0,00|0,00|0,00|0,00|0,00|"

print re.match("(\|.*?){23}", text).end() - 1
```

This gives 154 for your example text.

Comment: You could use `end()` instead of `span()[1]`. But in either case, you need to subtract 1, since your pattern matches past the required '|'. Also, you should use a raw string eg `r"(\|.*?){23}"` (or double that backslash).

Answer (score 1):

```
x = 0
for index, char in enumerate(string):
    if char == "|" and x == 23:
        output_index = index
    elif char == "|":
        x += 1
print output_index
```

enumerate() returns the index and value of each element in a string, list, dict, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re.finditer` to get a generator contain all groups contain `|` the use `re.matchObject.start()` method which return the start position of your match and get the 23th element with `enumerate` and a generator expression in `next` function  :

```
>>> all_case=re.finditer(r'\|',s)
>>> next(j.start() for i,j in enumerate(all_case,1) if i==23)
154
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `string.find()` within a loop and adjust the start index as you go. Something like the following:

```
start = -1
end = len(yourstring)
x = 0
while x < 23:
  start = string.find(yourstring, "|", start + 1, end)\
  x +=1
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming s is input string and you need to find position of nth |:

```
def find_position(s, n, c):
  return len("".join(s.split(c, maxsplit = n)[:n])) + n - 1
```

Comment: @PM2Ring Thanks for the idea. Will incorporate.

Comment: Ooops :) Better have to copy text next time rather than type :)